# PermissionDenied when trying to rename files and folders in a subdirectory

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell but thought it might be a good starting place for renaming all files and folders in a directory where they contain a string of 'UKLocal' and change that to be 'UKOutbound'

My current code just throws PermissionDenied and GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError errors.

```
$csprojFiles = Get-ChildItem . *. -rec
 foreach ($file in $csprojFiles)
 {
     (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
     Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "UKLocal", "UKOutbound" } |
     Set-Content $file.PSPath
 }
```

Comment: If i'm reading this right you're doing `Get-ChildItem -path . -filter *.`  . If so, what is the purpose of the -filter *. ? Is it make it just files? If so you might want to use -directory instead (if using PS3 or above).

Comment: Regarding you error, seems like you might not have permission to read/open the files at the Get-Content point. Do you have read permissions of all the files beneath the current directory (which is what . is representing in your get-childitem).

Comment: Your code won't rename folders as Get/Set-Content can only deal with text based files. The filter should be `*.*` if you are trying to use the filter to exclude folders. If you're using PS v3+ you can use the `-File` param instead like this: `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | foreach { (Get-Content $_.FullName).replace("UKLocal", "UKOutbound") | Set-Content $_.FullName }`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try an upgrade to p3

Comment: It's best to upgrade to the [latest version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395) of PowerShell rather than just use the version that came with Windows.